# Issues at using the Tensorflow Datasets API with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to fit a CNN Keras model, feeding it with data handled by the Datasets API from Tensorflow. However, I stumble again and again upon the same Exception, despite following the official documentation (see [there](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#input_tfdata_datasets)):

```
ValueError: No data provided for "conv2d_8_input". Need data for each key in: ['conv2d_8_input']
# conv2d_8 is the first Conv2D layer of my model, see below
```

I'm using the MNIST dataset from `tensorflow-datasets`, images are normalized and class labels are converted into one-hot encodings. You can see an excerpt from the code below.

```py
test_data, train_data = tfds.load("mnist", split=Split.ALL.subsplit([1, 3]))

# [...] Images are normalized using Dataset.map method
# [...] Labels are converted into one-hot encodings as well, using tf.one_hot function

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
        32,
        kernel_size=5,
        padding="same",
        input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
        activation="relu",
    ),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(
        (2, 2),
        padding="same"
    ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
        64,
        kernel_size=5,
        padding="same",
        activation="relu"
    ),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(
        (2, 2),
        padding="same"
    ),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(
        512,
        activation="relu"
    ),
    keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01),
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

train_data = train_data.batch(32).repeat()
test_data = test_data.batch(32).repeat()

model.fit(
    train_data,
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=30,
    validation_data=test_data,
    validation_steps=3
) # The exception occurs at this step
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, I tried to feed the fit method with one shot iterators instead of the datasets, but I get the same result. I'm not used to Keras and TensorFlow (I usually work with PyTorch), so I think I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: The MNIST dataset is of a different shape than 28,28,1. Do you have a reshape somewhere before the first conv2d ? For ex, refer https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn

Comment: @Prabindh well, it looks like the shape is indeed (28,28,1). A `print(train_data)` right before `model.fit(...)` yields the following output: `<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {image: (?, 28, 28, 1), label: (?, 10)}, types: {image: tf.float64, label: tf.uint8}>`. (The first unknown dimension is the batch dimension.)

Comment: I would assume that the dataset is broken. Have you tested whether it is non-empty/doesn't just return `None`?

Comment: @xdurch0 I am able to retrieve valid data from the Dataset (with a one shot iterator) and display the corresponding images and labels in a pyplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I enabled eager execution to see if Keras would yield a more precise exception, and I got this:

```
ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: {'image': <tf.Tensor: id=1012, shape=(32, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float64, numpy=array([...])>, 'label': <tf.Tensor: id=1013, shape=(32, 10), dtype=uint8, numpy=array([...]), dtype=uint8)>}
```

Indeed, the components of my datasets (images and their associated labels) have names ("image" and "label"), because this is how `tensorflow_datasets` loads them. As a result, an iterator on the datasets yields a dictionary with two values: "image" and "label".

However, [Keras expects a tuple](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator) of two values `(inputs, targets)` (or three values `(inputs, targets, sample_wheights)`), and it doesn't like the dictionary yielded by the Dataset iterator (hence the error I got).

I added the following code before `model.fit`:

```py
train_data = train_data.map(lambda x: tuple(x.values()))
test_data = test_data.map(lambda x: tuple(x.values()))
```

And it works.

Comment: I'm not fond of this solution to be honest, it doesn't seem clean. However, this is the only workaround I found to mitigate this limitation of Keras.

Comment: If you are using the TF version of keras, this should ideally not be required. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20698

Comment: @Prabindh I'm not sure this is entirely related, as I don't have a multi-input model? Should I mention my case on the github issue anyway?

Answer (score 3):

For those coming to this page after following TF 2.0 Beta tutorial on Loading images (https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/images):

I was able to avoid the error by returning a tuple in the preprocess_image function

```
def preprocess_image(image):
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
image = tf.image.resize(image, [192, 192])
image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
return (image,image)
```

I am not using the labels in my Use Case so you might have to do other changes to follow the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can load data from `tensorflow-datasets` directly as a tuple using `as_supervised`

```
test_data, train_data = tfds.load("mnist", split=tfds.Split.ALL.subsplit([1, 3]), as_supervised=True)
```